# Broadcast Receiver doesn't receive anything after sometime

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I know this type of question is already asked but none of them has a working solution.
I have an broadcast receiver which I registered in a service which works fine for one hour or more but does't receive anything after sometime.For further information service that triggers the receiver is always running.

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    this.mBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(this.mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Please Help.

Comment: May be because your app gets killed during that time.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said. can you explain in delete please.

Comment: Keeping the app idle for long time makes it a good candidate for garbage collection. And when your phone needs memory thereby GC runs  and Android system kills your application because it is idle and not active for a long period of time. Now when your app is no longer running, your receivers  are also unregistered and hence those doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Thanks. It definitely helps what  you told.  Do you know  any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had also same problem finally got a solution.
May be you are starting an activity on receiving an intent broadcast and in activity intent you might used have getApplicationContext() so when you your application is not running at all then the getApplicationContext() returns null and it will crash your receiver so you should use the same context which is received in onReceive method.
It was just a guess I hope it helps you.